# Types of convergences in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

I'm following a real analysis course and I tried to solve some exercise about various types of converges. In particular, I worked about this exercise:

[image]

This is my attempt:

[image]

[image]

Can you check if my solution is right?

PS: The part of the exercise 3 I used is this:

[image]

Comment: a) and c) are correct but there are errors in the statement of b). You have to replace $||f_j -f||_p$ by $||f_j -f||_{p,E}$  for b) to make sense. Otherwise, I think your solution is clean.

Comment: Thanks. But in the solution of (b) do you think there are mistakes or is it right?

Comment: Your solution to b) is also correct.